# Show few gps location on map

Tags: android, xml, google-maps, gps

I have been giving task to show 4 gps location on the map in the same time.
the coordinates recieved from XML file that hardcode in the project.

My question is:
How do hardcode the XML file in my project so i dont need to load the file?

My second question is:
How do i get the coordinates from the xml file?

here an example for XML file

**XML example**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><root><LastTrans><Vnumber>2057172</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:45:59.380</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.1968964e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4819195e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>ראשון לציון יהודה שגיא 22</Address><MileCounter>431148</MileCounter></LastTrans>
<LastTrans><Vnumber>2009072</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:26:59.790</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2055622e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4808765e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>תל אביב יפו דרך הטייסים 54</Address><MileCounter>279842</MileCounter></LastTrans>
<LastTrans><Vnumber>5083131</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:36:59.240</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2019333e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4943638e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>ברקת הזית 15</Address><MileCounter>445131</MileCounter></LastTrans>
<LastTrans><Vnumber>6308931</Vnumber><GPSDateTime>2016-05-28T20:57:59.130</GPSDateTime><Latitude>3.2025242e+001</Latitude><Longtitude>3.4869194e+001</Longtitude><IgnitionOn>0</IgnitionOn><Speed>0</Speed><Address>אור יהודה 37</Address><MileCounter>221326</MileCounter></LastTrans></root>
```

**Map example**

[image: mapexample]

on the map there 4 location.
my question is how do i hardcode an xml code and use it to get the latitude and longtitude to update the coordinates on the map.
thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Marker Class.

```
 Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
       .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
       .title("XXXXXXXXXXX"));
```

You can add Markers what you need.